# key value pair ordering in mongodb, how does it affects

Tags: mongodb, schema

While reading mongodb definitive guide I came across paragraph:
Key/value pairs in documents are ordered: `{x:1,y:2}` is not same as `{y:2,x:1}`. Field order does not usually matter and you should not design your schema to depend on a certain ordering of fields.

I wanted to know

- how the above x and y example is not same.
- can someone explain me with an instance of use case where schema
  design depends on a certain order of fields. And how different order
  affects programming logic if at all

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It matters if you do exact matching of an embedded object.

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "z" : { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 } })
> db.test.insert({ "z" : { "y" : 2, "x" : 1 } })
> db.test.count({ "z" : { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 } })
1
> db.test.count({ "z" : { "y" : 2, "x" : 1 } })
1
```

Don't design a schema that depends on this fact. You can match regardless of field order using dot notation.

```
> db.test.count({ "z.x" : 1, "z.y" : 2 })
2
```